# Uploading problems post Wordpress 3.3 upgrade

Tags: wordpress

Having upgraded to version 3.3 I can no longer upload files.

- The upload appears to work, progress bar runs without errors.
- Metadata can be amended.
- When visiting the files URL a 404 occurs.
- The file IS NOT written to the uploads directory.
- Upload directory has the correct permissions (755)

I'm thoroughly stumped - any ideas anyone?

Comment: Yes it does, tried there and no help, so thought I would give here shot since there is quite a big wordpress community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue pertains to the owner of an uploaded file.

In my case the website files were owned by the FTP user, not the web server user. It seems this wasn't an issue in older versions but now is and this caused the problems documented above.